# Realtek RTL8811CU Wifi Dongle

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, realtek

How may I get the USB Wifi recognized and operational when I plug it in?

When I use the `lsusb` command it shows:
`Realtek Semiconductor Corp`.

For the manufacturer I know the driver is **RTL8811CU**

On the package I can read:

```
Dual band USB Adapter;
600 mbps;
2.4 GHz + 5 GHz;
USB 2.0 High-Speed;
IEEE: 802.11 ac;
Supported OS: Windows XP/Vista/7/8/10/Mac/Linux;
```

My Ubuntu OS is:

```
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS;
Release: 18.04;
Codename: bionic;
```

My linux kernel version is:

```
4.15.0-88-generic
```

Comment: use this driver for support of the latest version of the Linux kernel.  https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu-20210916

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work. Just open your network configuration manager and connect to your wi-fi hotspot.

In my case it is in **Main menu -> Preferences -> Settings -> Wi-Fi**:
[image]

If your adapter does not work, you [could try](https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU):

- `sudo apt install dkms -y`
- `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- [then](https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU)

  > Plug your USB-wifi-adapter into your PC 
  > If wifi can be detected,
  >   congratulations. If not, maybe you need to switch your device usb mode
  >   by the following steps in terminal:
  >
  > find your usb-wifi-adapter device ID, like `0bda:1a2b`, by type: 
  > `lsusb`
  >   switch the mode by type: (the device ID must be yours.) Need install
  >   `usb_modeswitch`
  >
  > `sudo usb_modeswitch -KW -v 0bda -p 1a2b`
  >  It should work.
- or, if previous did not help:

  ```
  sudo apt install build-essential -y
  mkdir -p ~/build
  cd ~/build
  sudo apt install git
  git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
  cd rtl8821CU
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. 
But it didn't solve the issue. The point is that my OS isn't recognizing the USB dongle plugged in. Because I think there's no driver for it on the default list. So I asked for help: someone who owns the driver and could provide it to me and guide me through the driver installation.

Comment: Ok. I've edited answer. Could you try it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. It worked with the last par of commands you provided me (your "or" part). I really appreciate your help. Wish you all the very best!

Comment: No problem) Glad it helped. It's not mine solution, but driver author's

Comment: Even after more than 2 years the `brektrou` driver solution still needed for the device to work.

Comment: The last step worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04. wifi device is `0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC`

Answer (score 1):

It works with mercusys ac650, but only in 2GHhz. It was a lot of work, so I'm so grateful for the help.

Do you know some way that can work with wifi 5GHz?, but either way I'm so grateful.

For those who have the same device that I have https://www.mercusys.com/en/product/details/mu6h the 3rd option works.

```
sudo apt install build-essential -y
mkdir -p ~/build
cd ~/build
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
cd rtl8821CU
make
sudo make install
```