# DMG-19 WiFi stick with RTL8811cu and Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, realtek-wireless

I've just bought a new WiFi stick DMG-19 and wanted to use its 5Ghz ability, because my current laptop internal WiFi module doesn't work in this frequency. The stick works under my friend's Windows 10 (I see Wireless network 2 in the list and can connect without any problems) but I have problems with making it work on my Kubuntu 16.04 system.

`$lsb_release -a`
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04

My kernel is 4.4.0-177-generic #207-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 16 01:16:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Info on the box says, it uses RTL8811cu chipset, so as it mentions here [Realtek RTL8811CU Wifi Dongle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211456/realtek-rtl8811cu-wifi-dongle)  I downloaded the repo and installed the driver. And after I have:

`$ dkms status`
rtl8821CU, 5.4.1, 4.4.0-177-generic, x86_64: installed

`$ lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp.   
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174f:114f Syntek   
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Device 005 is the stick. When I check `lsmod` on this step, it doesn't show the 8821cu, so I go to /lib/modules/4.4.0-177-generic/updates/dkms  and run `sudo modprobe 8821cu`, which is found in the directory. Then

`$ lsmod | grep 8821`

```
8821cu               2211840  0  
cfg80211              565248  4 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm,8821cu
```

`$ dmesg | grep 8821cu`

```
[ 2296.746080] 8821cu: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.  
[ 2296.748542] 8821cu: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel  
[ 2296.761367] RTW: rtl8821cu v5.4.1_28754.20180921_COEX20180712-3232  
[ 2296.761372] RTW: rtl8821cu BT-Coex version = COEX20180712-3232  
[ 2296.761472] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8821cu
```

`$ rfkill list`

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

But I don't see its interface here

`$ iwconfig`

```
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"L&A"    
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: D8:07:B6:4E:C9:93     
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off  
          Power Management:on  
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-31 dBm    
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0  
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:560   Missed beacon:0  

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.  

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

And
`$ sudo lshw -C network` shows this picture, where I also doesn't see the device:

```
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8172 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 20:1a:06:8e:68:69
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:32 memory:d8500000-d853ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 135
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: c4
       serial: 0c:d2:92:ae:bf:8c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-177-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.0.160 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:30 memory:d8400000-d8401fff
```

What am I doing wrong? I also tried to edit one file with 1A2B device, as said here https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=230499  and also tried the driver from the repository in that answer.

Comment: FYI: Kubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Kubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks, or use Ubuntu's default Unity desktop (*which still is supported*).

Comment: Also note, your system is not fully-updated, as an *up-to-date* 16.04 system will report itself as 16.04.7, meaning you're also behind on security fixes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I understand the need to upgrade to new OS Version, but at the same time it is now configured for my work very well, and I am afraid to loose very painfully installed remmina/vnc remote connection to my work station and can't upgrade in the near future. Also I use Mysql Workbench at work, and my college, who moved to 20.04 now has many problems with it, and I don't want to get into this situation, too.

Comment: @guiverc, I tried to update my system, after sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get upgrade it still says 16.04.6 LTS. Does it mean that it was not successful? Or it is ok?

Comment: Try `sudo apt full-upgrade` as `upgrade` works with some limitations so won't fully upgrade your system (`full-upgrade` does that). I'm associated with a *flavor* and we support LTS releases only 3 years, and we don't want to encourage use beyond it's intended & supported life, so whilst I won't close vote your question (the 16.04 base is still supported), I (*and a number of others*) won't provide help for it either. You're most welcome to keep using the software. (FYI: 16.04 LTS will *release-upgrade* to 18.04)